# separating the output with title

Tags: powershell

I have customized a script so that 3 MetricName ‘s can be pulled with this script which is happening fine. But problem is that output will provide their values in a list (as attached here) so it is difficult make out which value is meant for which MetricName. Can some one please help me here so that the output values will have a title so that I can easily identify the metrics with correspondent values.

```
$metric =
Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/111111-3333-4444-666666/resourceGroups/ad-fg-ggproviders/Microsoft.Sql/servers/server/databases/db01" -MetricName @('CPU_used','cpu_percent','deadlock') -DetailedOutput

$metric.Data
```

[image]

Comment: This is how PowerShell displays the objects to the console, you can try piping that result to `Format-Table -Auto` but if you're worried about data export, for example CSV then there is no need to worry about it.

Comment: As @Santi mentions, PowerShell formats the output as a List when 5, or more properties are returned. Either select just 4, or pipe to `Format-Table` as he mentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map the metric names back to the corresponding output in the data list by index.

I'd suggest writing a small function to handle that:

```
function Get-AggregateAzMetric
{
  param(
    [string]$ResourceId,
    [string[]]$MetricName
  )

  $metric = Get-AzMetric @PSBoundParameters -DetailedOutput

  # prepare dictionary to hold properties that we want the output object to have
  $outputProperties = [ordered]@{
      TimeStamp = $metric.Data[0].Timestamp
  }

  for($i = 0; $i -lt $MetricName.Length; $i++){
    # Grab the metric name from the input list - map to the corresponding metric value
    $outputProperties[$MetricName[$i]]  =  $metric.Data[$i].Average
  }

  # convert the properties we've collected to a custom object
  [pscustomobject]$outputProperties
}
```

Once you've defined the above function, you can do:

```
Get-AggregateAzMetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/111111-3333-4444-666666/resourceGroups/ad-fg-ggproviders/Microsoft.Sql/servers/server/databases/db01" -MetricName @('CPU_used','cpu_percent','deadlock')
```

Since the resulting object will only have 4 properties (`Timestamp`, `CPU_used`, `cpu_percent`, and `deadlock`), PowerShell will default to show it in a table view.

For objects with more than 4 visible properties, you can also use `Format-Table` to explicitly request table view formatting:

```
$aggMetric = Get-AggregateAzMetric -MetricName @('CPU_used','cpu_percent','deadlock','log_write_percent') -ResourceId "/subscriptions/111111-3333-4444-666666/resourceGroups/ad-fg-ggproviders/Microsoft.Sql/servers/server/databases/db01"

# this will default to a list view
$aggMetric |Out-Default

# but you can request a different format if you want to
$aggMetric |Format-Table
```

Comment: Hi Mathias , its providing the output now, but what i see the values its showing are wrong , example “deadlock” should be 0 by the time I am running this script but its showing 0.8


TimeStamp           CPU_used cpu_percent deadlock log_write_percent
---------           -------- ----------- -------- -----------------
3/4/2022 3:01:00 AM      0.8         0.6      0.8               0.8

Comment: looks like Get-AggregateAzMetric command is not collecting the exact value, any bug?

Comment: If Azure Monitor is giving erroneous responses then you need to contact Azure support, I can't help with that :)

Comment: thanks will do....